# dynamic way to print same line multiple times in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I have some set of operations and I want to display a seperation line after completing each operation. (For better readability)

My code:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     line='-'*100

     print line
     #do something

     print line
     #do something

     print line
     #do something
```

This exactly does what I want. But the problem here is I have 100's of operations. Later, if I want to stop displaying lines, I have to remove `print line` from everywhere.

Another solution might be managing some global flag to check whether to display line or not.

Is there any other simple & dynamic solution to this issue ?

Comment: You wouldn't actually have to remove the `print line` from everywhere. Maybe just set `line = ''` instead.

Comment: `def print_separator(): print(line)` and latter replace the body of the function with `pass` or add a conditional operator into it when you want to get rid of the separator.

Answer (score 2):

You may have fallen into the trap of copy pasting the same things 100s of time. I can't comment and ask, but if you're `# do somethings` are the same, you can do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = '-' * 100
    for _ in range(<how many times>):
        print line
        # do something
```

If they're not the same, they should really be functions as there shouldn't be too much code outside functions. For example,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    line = '-' * 100

    print line
    function_a()

    print line
    function_b()

    print line
    function_c()

    # etc
```

becomes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    line = '-' * 100

    for function in (function_a, function_b,  # etc
                     function_c):
        print line
        function()
```

Comment: The second solution (looping over a tuple of functions) looks nice. It won't fit all tasks though.

Comment: @Artyer : All the # do somethings are different functions and prints different  output to console.

Comment: @Dave Would the second solution be appropriate? Otherwise, I'm afraid you are going to have to go with the global flag.

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean variable at the top and use it to control the print statements:

```
print_lines = True  # Change to False when you no longer want to print
if print_lines:
    print line
```

Comment: I have already mentioned this in my question as a "another solution". i don't want to put if condition 100's of times.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed it while reading your question. This is the simplest solution I use for these kinds of things.